# How to place chords over lyrics in Java and keep them above the right syllabe?

Tags: java, android

sorry for my dumb question, but i need some help.

I'm making an app that shows the lyrics and chords of songs. I need to place the chord letter above the correct syllable of the word. Example:

"[G]These are the lyrics o[Am]f the song"

so the expected outcome for the above example is:

```
G                    Am
These are the lyrics of the song
```

See that the chord letters should stay above the correct word. I don't know how to achieve this.

I found a similar question but it was for javascript: [Format lyrics with inline notes to readable song with chords on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65273298/format-lyrics-with-inline-notes-to-readable-song-with-chords-on-top)

It is possible to achieve this?

Sorry about my English.

I really don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please take the [tour], and have a read through [ask]. You need to provide a [mcve] showing what you have tried so far and where you have failed.

Comment: There's nothing built in for that, you're going to have to so something custom.  Probably the easiest way is a custom view, splitting the string into 1 string per chord and drawing both the lyrics and chord via drawText commands.